# MiKTeX missing error message

Tags: errors, miktex

I used the command to suppress the screen output

```
latex -quiet foo.tex
```

`--quiet` is implemented in MiKTeX's executables and removes all the stuff from the output stream except for the errors.

It displays as below

```
foo.tex:3:
```

but the MiKTeX error should display like below

```
foo.tex:3: Undefined control sequence
```

Here the error message not showing. It shows only line number. Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: The `foo.log` file should still show all the messages including the full error message.

Comment: I do not observe this behaviour with a recently updated MiKTeX. So the usual demand: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The code producing here a line like you miss it:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textf{XYZ}
\end{document}